How to add multiple widgets on KivyMD Tabs?
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.tab import (
    MDTabsItemIcon,
    MDTabsItemText,
    MDTabsItem,
)

KV = '''
MDScreen:
    md_bg_color: self.theme_cls.backgroundColor

    MDTabsPrimary:
        id: tabs
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
        size_hint_x: .6

        MDDivider:

        MDTabsCarousel:
            id: related_content_container
            size_hint_y: None
            height: dp(320)
'''


class Example(MDApp):
    def on_start(self):
        super().on_start()
        for tab_icon, tab_name in {
            "airplane": "Flights",
            "treasure-chest": "Trips",
            "compass-outline": "Explore",
        }.items():
            self.root.ids.tabs.add_widget(
                MDTabsItem(
                    MDTabsItemIcon(
                        icon=tab_icon,
                    ),
                    MDTabsItemText(
                        text=tab_name,
                    ),
                ),
            )
            self.root.ids.related_content_container.add_widget(
                MDLabel(
                    text=tab_name,
                    halign="center",
                )
            ),
            self.root.ids.related_content_container.add_widget(
                MDLabel(
                    text='Treasure',
                    halign="center",
                )
            ),
            self.root.ids.related_content_container.add_widget(
                MDLabel(
                    text='Compass',
                    halign="center",
                )
            )
            
        self.root.ids.tabs.switch_tab(icon="airplane")

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Olive"
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


Example().run()

I'm new to KivyMD and need help. I'm using this code to create tabs with KivyMD. I'm trying to add multiple widgets to each tab. Here, I am attempting to add three labels to each tab. However, I'm only seeing one label on each tab: the first tab shows the tab name, the second tab shows 'Treasure', and the third tab shows 'Compass'.
Here, after using the 'related_content_container' ID, I expected to see all three labels—'tab_name,' 'Treasure,' and 'Compass'—on each tab. However, when I run the code, it doesn't display as expected. Moreover,what does MDDivider do?
